# Using vimeo.ga.js plugin correctly

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, vimeo

This is a very simple question, but one that I can't find the answer to anywhere. I want to use vimeo.ga.js to track plays for Vimeo videos on my site. I loaded the library:

```
<script src="js/libs/vimeo.ga.min.js"></script>
```

And changed by videos to have ids:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/154057227?api=1&player_id=vimeo-player-1" id="vimeo-player-1" data-progress="true" width="400" height="320" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now I think I need to put this somewhere, I just don't know where.

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Vimeo', 'Started video', 'https://player.vimeo.com/video/154057227', undefined, {'nonInteraction': 1});
```

Any help would be very much appreciated,

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the ga(send) line anywhere, it's already in the script. Sometimes it works when you load the Vimeo js after the video, like in the footer. Just start interacting with the embedded Vimeo video and monitor your real-time reports in GA to see if it works.